# vsftpd error with self-signed certificates in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, vsftpd, certificates

I am setting up an FTP server and I need to use my own self-signed certificates for FTPS. When I configure vsftpd to use my self-signed certificates it fails to start.

The exact same setup works without issue in Ubuntu 18.04 (both are AWS EC2 instances). I am using vsftpd version 3.0.3 in both cases.

This is how I am creating the certificates:

```
mkdir certificates && cd certificates
mkdir ubxtestCA && cd ubxtestCA
CANAME=ubxtestCA
CLIENTNAME=ubxtestclient
SERVERNAME=ubxtest.ddns.net
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -extensions v3_ca -keyout $CANAME.key -out $CANAME.crt &&
openssl genrsa -out $CLIENTNAME.key 1024 &&
openssl req -out $CLIENTNAME.csr -key $CLIENTNAME.key -new &&
openssl x509 -req -in $CLIENTNAME.csr -CA $CANAME.crt -CAkey $CANAME.key -CAcreateserial -out $CLIENTNAME.crt -days 365 &&
openssl genrsa  -out $SERVERNAME.key 1024 &&
openssl req -out $SERVERNAME.csr -key $SERVERNAME.key -new &&
openssl x509 -req -in $SERVERNAME.csr -CA $CANAME.crt -CAkey $CANAME.key -CAcreateserial -out $SERVERNAME.crt -days 360
```

My deployment process is as follows:

- deploy AWS EC2 instance
- sudo apt update
- create certificates
- sudo apt install vsftpd
- edit /etc/vsftpd.conf to change rsa_cert_file and rsa_private_key to my new certificates
- sudo systemctl restart vsftpd
- sudo systemctl status vsftpd

After restarting vsftpd the status shows:

- vsftpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT

If I copy the vsftpd snakeoil certificates into the same directory as my own certificates and point to these in the vsftpd.conf file, this also works.

If I follow the exact same process on Ubuntu 18.04 I do not get any errors and my certificates work (client is able to validate the server identity).

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the problem.

For some reason VSFTPD (on Ubuntu 20.04) does not work with a certificate that uses a 1024 bit key. After changing the keys generated in my example to 2048 bits, it works.

Strange...

Update 10/7/20: As suggested in the comments here are details about how I identified the source of this issue:

I compared the working snakeoil certificate included with vsftpd to my certificate. This was done with the command:

```
openssl x509 -in <certificate_file> -text -noout
```

I changed one aspect of my certificate at a time to match the snakeoil certificate until the vsftpd error went away. I tried changing the subject to only include the CN field (removing  C, ST, L, O, OU, and emailAddress fields). I also changed the certificate from version 1 to version 3. Finally changing the RSA key used to 2048 bits allowed vsftpd to successfully start up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Nmath. I've updated my answer to explain how I figured this out.